# sql update throw error when update result go below zero

Tags: mysql, database, sql-update

How can I make SQL update throw error when update result go below zero !!?

what I have try is

```
UPDATE round_table SET table_seat = table_seat - number WHERE table_name = data;
```

Change Attribute to UNSIGN value

==================================

it's still execute below zero or not expect number but, It doesn't throw any error

sometime it execute but no affected row which not I expect.

==================================

Can I let SQL throw error when data go below 0 after updated.

Comment: Which do you want. table_seat not allowed to be negative, or to detect  ones that have?

Comment: table_seat not allow sir

Comment: With every other DBMS you would simply create a check constraint....

Comment: I alter table constraint but it seem no effect at all do you have any example?

Answer (score 0):

One way.

```
UPDATE round_table SET table_seat = table_seat - number WHERE table_name = data
And table_seat >= number
```

If you get no rows affected, either the table_name is not present (which appears to be one of your other issues) or table_seat would have gone < 0.

Comment: I have already tell that I have try this issue already,but thank any way

Comment: Ah now I see what you are getting at. Would this help. https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/signal.html

Answer (score -1):

If you use php you can check this code for mysqli

```
<?php

if ($mysqli->affected_rows  ==0)
    throw new Exception('The Result is 0 Now');
```

Or this

```
<?php

if (mysql_affected_rows()  ==0)
    throw new Exception('The Result is 0 Now');
```

For mysql

Comment: I have use mysqli->multi_query so there will be some rows affected and some not. SO, this method wouldn't work in this case I think

Comment: Tony wants to check if the result of `table_seat - number` is below zero, not the number of affected rows.